# Use ImageMagick to crop text field from image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, crop

I would like to use ImageMagick to crop everything from an image except a text field with black background (see example below).  The goal is to isolate the black area for additional work on the text image.  I need to do those for hundreds of images, and the target area shifts slightly between images (the images are screen grabs from a film video).

So, I need to adaptively identify the region with a black background, then remove everything else from the image.

For example, turn this:
[image]

Into this:
[image]

The main concern is that the bottom left edge of the region of interest is aligned across all the hundreds of images.

Comment: Cool question, can I have a couple more images to test out when I get up tomorrow please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject to looking at some more examples, you could threshold and do a *"Connected Component Analysis"* like this and look for the widest black region:

```
convert frame.png -threshold 30%                     \
    -define connected-components:verbose=true        \
    -define connected-components:area-threshold=5000 \
    -connected-components 4 -auto-level output.png

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  1: 720x480+0+0 357.3,232.9 334572 srgb(255,255,255)
  27: 542x40+93+416 426.1,441.0 11028 srgb(0,0,0)
```

If I draw in, in red, the second blob identified (you can see it is black, wide and not very tall):

```
convert frame.png -fill none -stroke red -draw "rectangle 93,416 635,456" output.png
```

[image]

You can crop it out with a similar command:

```
convert frame.png -crop 542x40+93+416 output.png
```

[image]

Tages: Timecode, time-code, video

Comment: Thanks @Mark, this looks promising.  I will test it out and also try and share a few more pictures with you.  Is there a reasonably easy way to save or pass on those crop coordinates from the verbose output?

Comment: Excellent! You may want to reduce the `30%` a bit. You can capture the coordinates easily enough, but the method depends on which OS you use - Linux/OSX/Windows? You could also pre-crop the image to just the likely area of the text to improve accuracy.

Comment: I just tested it on a few pictures and the text areas are aligning much better.  I'm actually wrapping the whole process in a Python script using the `subprocess.call` command, and I think I can figure out a way to get the coordinates fed back into Python.  This is definitely a great starting point, there's so much ImageMagick can do!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! I am pleased to be of service - and good luck with your project! There is an ImageMagick port to Python by the way, but I don't speak Python myself.